# Can a seed phrase generated to create a MetaMask wallet also be recovered on a hardware wallet?

Tags: metamask, recovery, hardware-wallets

A hardware wallet address can be recovered in MetaMask simply be entering the hardware wallet's seed phrase into MetaMask. But does this work the other way too, where the seed phrase of a MetaMask wallet is entered into and recovered on a hardware wallet?

Comment: I think Ledger 24 words seeds are compatible with Metamask 24, it seems it supports 12 words seeds https://www.reddit.com/r/ledgerwallet/comments/ayf1qh/12_word_seed/ although it doesn't generate them.

Comment: If the seed-phrase for MetaMask wallet #1 is also the same for a secondary MetaMask wallet #2 the user creates under it, is it possible to recover wallet #2 by itself on a hardware wallet? Or will that seed-phrase always recover both wallets #1 and #2 inseparably?

Comment: In theory yes, but it depends on the application used to manage the wallet. Ledger Live does allow access to several accounts generated from the seed.

Comment: How? assuming wallet #2 generated in MetaMask is what we would like to recover solely on the Ledger

Comment: I've no idea how it is done, but you can have several addresses. It is common with coins like bitcoin to have multiple adresses and most wallets support it.